# Not inserting a ACL Role using ACL Role API

Tags: api, acl

I was trying to assigning a new Users to CiviCRM ACL role through ACL Role API, but it is not showing me in database.

> Input json

```
     $result = civicrm_api3('AclRole', 'create', [
  'debug' => 1,
  'sequential' => 1,
  'acl_role_id' => 14,
  'entity_table' => "civicrm_group",
  'entity_id' => 54,
  'is_active' => 1,

]);
```

> Output json

```
"values": [
    {
        "id": "14",
        "acl_role_id": "",
        "entity_table": "civicrm_group",
        "entity_id": "54",
        "is_active": "1"
    }
]
```

I already providing a "acl_role_id", but in the output json object, it is showing a blank

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the value 14 for acl_role_id is correct.

ACL role is an option value pair and should to be set as one of the existing value available from `civicrm/admin/options/acl_role?reset=1`.

UPDATE - just tried on my local and looks like a bug to me. Can you raise this as a new ticket at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/new?

Comment: The acl_role_id is correct (I checked both civicrm_group and role_id in database). I tried by using UI and it worked. But not working using API.